# BNF grammar of my xml

Tags: xml, grammar, bnf

I wrote simple class code generator, that creates code basing on xml file.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classes>
    <class name="Klient">
        <attr type="int">id</attr>
        <attr type="String">imie</attr>
        <attr type="String">nazwisko</attr>
        <attr type="Date">dataUr</attr>
    </class>
    <class name="Wizyta">
        <attr type="int">id</attr>
        <attr type="Klient">klient</attr>
        <attr type="Date">data</attr>
    </class>
</classes>
```

If I wanted to define this simple xml as a BNF grammar, how it would look like?

Comment: You need to decide if you want to support something which is a kind of simplified XML (for which you can likely write a parser pretty quickly), or handles the full glory of the XML standard (at which point writing your own parser becomes and enormous task, and you should just use an existing package).

Comment: For reference: [full BNF for XML](http://www.cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/xmlgrammar/), [official XML W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) (contains all BNF productions interspersed with definitions, examples, comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how loose you want the grammar to be. For example, making some clear assumptions:

```
data       -> version '<classes>' classes '</classes>'
version    -> '<?xml version=' quotedString 'encoding=' quotedString '?>'
classes    -> '<class name=' quotedString '>' attributes '</class>' classes
attributes -> '<attr type=' quotedString '>' string '</attr>' attributes
```

(quotedString and string are terminals and all other terminals are between quotes)

Note how you could eliminate some productions from the grammar above, but that wouldn't improve readability.

As for the actual usage of this grammar: **consider using an XML parsing library**, that will probably be much more easier than using an actual parser generator (let alone manually implementing one).